# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. when ever make change in html files

Tags: angular

ngFor is working fine when I run ng serve. I can navigate to every pages easily without any error

**But when I change any line in html file like xyz.component.html then the app compiled successfully but in console i got the error Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' **

Please provide me some solution to resolve this.

```
<div class="dashboard row">
<div class="card col-lg-3" *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{card.title}}</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li *ngFor="let cardFeature of cardFeatures" style="padding-left: 7px;">
                <a href="" *ngIf="cardFeature.enable" [routerLink]="cardFeature.link">{{cardFeature.title}}</a>    
                <!-- <button type="submit>Submit</button> -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share more details because we cant help with information that you provided.

Comment: add related code where you'r getting the excaption

Comment: can you share the template with us 

Comment: why don't you upload your hmtl?

Comment: Hi all I have edited the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you imported `BrowserModule` in your topmost module i.e `app.module.ts`. All the child modules will import `CommonModule`.

If it is still not resolved then try to disable IVY engine by setting the following boolean value as false in  **tsconfig.app.json** file

```
"enableIvy": false
```

and in the **angular.json** file, remove `aot` line

```
"aot": true
```

Comment: Cool. I am just removing aot: true bcz I need enableIvy to true. And hopefully rwmoving aot: true has worked .Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a `let` keyword inside your `*ngFor`. You might be missing that one even though you've imported the modules on your `app.module.ts`

```
<h2>My Data</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of data">{{ d.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have let in my ngFor loop. Thanks for your response.