# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li' Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

This question has been asked multiple times here and after going through enough solutions, I am positing because the common solution of making sure I have `CommonModule` in my child module and `BrowserModule` in my app.module.ts is not working.

HTML Child-Module

```
<div class="container bg-success">
  hi  <---- this works just fine
</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products">
    <h2>{{ product.name }} ${{ product.id}}</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

component in child-module

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.css'],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Licensed Frozen Hat',
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Child Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChildComponent} from './components/child-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ChildComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

App Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ConfigurationModule } from './modules/configuration/configuration.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ConfigurationModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Rerun ng serve.

Comment: @EliyaCohen, I effin hate this. I have been at this for an hour and I did not think of re running ng serve. This is BS. Damit.
Thanks !!!!

Comment: If possible can you create in stackblitz.com

Comment: Been there :) usually happens when add a new module/package

Comment: re-running ng serve should not be the fix

Comment: @Maccurt, in my case, that was the fix

Comment: I am confused, because while that does fix it for me, the problem keeps coming back and  I have to keep re-running ng serve. I turned off AOT and  disabled EnableIvy and that seemed to work better for me for the time being. I will get back to you if that ultimately fixed it for me.

Comment: See also this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706164/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div-when-ever-make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eliya Cohen mentioned in the comment above, rerunning ng serve fixed it for me. Keep this just in case someone runs into this.